# Java Json / Gson put json encoded string to jsonObject without string escapes

Tags: java, json, reference, gson

i first create a Json String with

```
String myJsonString = new Gson().toJson(myElement);
```

this works fine.
After that, i want to add this String to anothe big jsonObject to send it to backend with other vars.

```
jsonObject.put("Tests",myJsonString);
```

but with this line of code the special character will be escaped and the parser on the backend didnt get it.
How can I avoid it, that myJsonString will be serialized again?

```
jsonObject.put("Tests",myElement);
```

doesnt work, because after that there are only references in the jsonObject but no values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jsonObject.put("Tests", new JSONObject(myJsonString));
```

(assuming jsonObject is of type [org.json.JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html))